# ¿Como lograr iniciar sesión con el registro de contraseña encriptado desde la base de datos?

Tags: php

Que tal camaradas estoy creando un formulario de regsitro y login en android studio, dese la app guardo los datos y encriptado de password desde PHP, y el detalle es que cuando quiero iniciar sesión ya con el pass encriptado no puedo acceder he implementado algunos métodos desde PHP, he visto aquí mismo en esta página algo parecido pero no he tenido resultados favorables.

**registroUsuario.php**

```
<?PHP

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  require_once("conexion.php");

  $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
  $nombreUsuario = $_POST["nombreUsuario"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $pass = $_POST["pass"];
  }

  $encryp = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  $query = "INSERT INTO t_usuario_final(nombre,nombreUsuario,email,pass) VALUES('$nombre', '$nombreUsuario', '$email','$encryp')";
 $result = $mysql->query($query);

 if ($result === true) {
 echo "Datos intsertados correctamente";

 } else {
 echo "Datos no insertados";
 }
 $mysql->close();
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

  $con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","logishuman");

  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $pass = $_POST["pass"];

  if (empty($email) || empty($pass)) {
  echo "0";
  } else {
 $st_check=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_usuario_final WHERE email=? AND pass=?");
    $st_check->bind_param("ss", $_POST["email"],$_POST["pass"]);
    $st_check->execute();
    $rs=$st_check->get_result();
    if($rs->num_rows==0){
      echo "1";
    }
    else{
      echo "2";
    }
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera observación  que puedo hacer es que estas usando dos conexiones distintas, una en tu  registroUsuario.php y definiste otra en tu login.php. Esto no es un error pero seria mejor si usas la misma conexión para todos tus formularios.

Ahora bien, para desencriptar una contraseña que previamente encriptaste con el metodo `password_hash()` (como lo hiciste en registroUsuario.php) debes usar el metodo password_verify().

El metodo password_verify() requiere 2 argumentos (parametros) obligatorios, el primero es la contraseña que el usuario ingresa en el login, el segundo es la contraseña encriptada en la base de datos (que se guardo cuando el usuario se registró).

Lo primero que deberías hacer es verificar si el usuario existe por el email, si el email es correcto, seleccionas los datos del usuario y entonces verificas si la contraseña es correcta, de esta forma sabrás si hay un error con el email o la contraseña.

Así es como se vería tu código, lo probé con mi bd y me funciona.

```
//datos recibidos por POST
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];


$con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","logishuman");

//siempre checkea si hay errores con la coneccion
if($con->connect_error)
{
    die("Coneccion fallida ". $con->connect_error);
}

//Observacion: deberias aplicar el operador && (y) en vez de || (o)
if(empty($email) || empty($pass)){

    //retornar el usuario al login con mensaje que los campos no pueden estar vacios
    echo "0";
}
else{

    // Verifica primero si el email es valido (si existe en la base de datos)
    $st_check = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_usuario_final WHERE email=?");
    $st_check->bind_param('s',$email);

    //Ya que execute() retorna boolean puedes ejecutarlo en un if 
    if($st_check->execute())
    {
        //obtener los resultados en la variable $results
        $results = $st_check->get_result();

        // verifica si el email coincide en la base de datos 
        // Tu logica deberia ser si "num_rows" es igual a 1 no 0, es decir si hay una unica fila en la base de datos con ese email
        if($results->num_rows == 1)
        {

            //obtener los datos del usuario
            $usuario = $results->fetch_assoc();

            // ahora que ya sabes que el email es correcto, verificas si la contraseña es correcta
            // el primar argumento $pass es la variable $pass que definiste arriba
            // el segundo argumento $usuario["pass"]  es la contraseña encriptada que tomaste de la base de datos con fetch_assoc()
            if(password_verify($pass, $usuario["pass"]))
            {
                // La contrasena es valida, estas logeado
                echo "1";
            }
            else
            {
                // La contrasena es incorrecta
                echo "2";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // El email proporcionado por el usuario no existe en la base de datos
            echo "Error: email incorrecto";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // El metodo execute() no se ejecuto
    "Error: no se pudo ejecutar la consulta";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Solo como observación en: *Ahora bien, para desencriptar una contraseña...*, si la contraseña ya fue *hasheada* no se recupera el valor inicial, solo [*Comprueba que la contraseña coincida con un hash*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Si  es cierto, solo verifica si la contraseña coincide, no la desencripta ni la recupera. Gracias por la observacion @BetaM.

Comment: @AryRodny que tal amigo, implemente tu código y si me funciono, nomas que en las validaciones como la "Contraseña incorrecta" y "Email incorrecto" las cambie en las dos por "contraseña o email incorrectos" de esta forma confundimos al enemigo, gracias .